# Regex - Find all Elements with Certain IDs

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to find all <*style> tags within HTML, with only a certain ID for instance (code should only return the tags with fixed_id):

```
<style id="fixed_id" type="text/css">all css code</style>
```

I have the following code..

```
$html = '<style id="fixed_id" type="text/css">css_code</style><style id="ignore_this" type="text/css"></style>';    
preg_match_all("@<style[^>]+(id=['\"fixed_id\"]?)[^>]+(type=['\"]?[^'\"]+['\"]?)?[^>]+?>(.+?)</style>@is", $html, $matches);
```

I also need to remove all those <*style> tags with certain IDs, for that I am using the following code which obviously is not selecting the right selector but removing all <*style> tags.

```
$html = preg_replace("/<style\\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\\/style>/s", "", $html);
```

Comment: what is a question ?

Comment: See http://ideone.com/XwZ0h3

Comment: Please try my code - I think it does what you need: 1) collects style tags with id=fixed_id and 2) removes them from the html code. If you have normal html code, you do not need the fake tags I added and then the substr at the end will be redundant, too.

Comment: Thanks stribiz.. I can see the output.. it looks clean short awesome, my problem is I have to add many checks and custom replacement of codes.. so I find the regex more easy.. but I will try to adopt your code and report back... thanks once again for your time and quick solutions...

Comment: Wait, if you have to do more, that is another question. This one is about extracting and deleting from HTML code. Do you think I should post my solution with explanations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Notice: Assigning same ID to multiple tags is semantically wrong. One
>   tag - one ID.

**For removing all those <*style> tags with certain ID:**

```
$html = '<style id="ignore_this" type="text/css"></style><style class="test_class" id="fixed_id" type="text/css">css_code</style><style id="ignore_this" type="text/css"></style>';

$id = "fixed_id"; // could be any other value
$res = preg_replace('/<style(\s+([a-z\-]+)=(\'|\")([^\"\'>]*)(\'|\"))* id="' . $id .'" .*?>.*?<\/style>/i', "", $html);

var_dump($res);
// outputs '<style id="ignore_this" type="text/css"></style><style id="ignore_this" type="text/css"></style>'
```

---

**To find <*style> tag with only a certain ID:**

```
// I've changed IDs to be unique
$html = '<style id="ignore_this" type="text/css"></style><style class="test_class" id="fixed_id" type="text/css">css_code</style><style id="ignore_this2" type="text/css"></style><style data-id="111" id="fixed_id2" type="text/css">css content</style>';
preg_match_all('/<style(\s+([a-z\-]+)=(\'|\")([^\"\'>]*)(\'|\"))* id="' . $id .'" .*?>(?P<value>.*?)<\/style>/i', $html, $matches);

var_dump($matches['value']);  // using named submask to indicate captured tag value(text)
// outputs value of the captured tag as expected
0 => string 'css_code'
```

---

I also recommend you to use `DOMDocument` for such goals(manipulating html content). It lets you to process html content in more precise and extensive way.

```
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html); // $html from above

$xpath = new \DOMXPath($doc);
$id = "fixed_id"; // could be any other value
foreach ($xpath->query('//style[@id="'.$id.'"]') as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue;
}
// outputs 'css_code' as expected
```

Comment: What if `id` attribute is preceded with other attributes? What if there are newline symbols?

Comment: Thanks stribizhev.. I saw your code, but its advance than my level :) so I will adopt a simple version if possible like this.. Hi Roman.. how about finding all tags with fixed_id ?..

Comment: thanks for comments. I've updated my solution regarding to possible preceding tags

Comment: Thanks Roman, for finding all Ids, it partially works as desired, it collects all full line, I mean e.g. <*style id="fixed_id" type="text/css">css code<*/style> where the original code I posted grabs the content inside the <*style> tag, can you please slightly modify it and make that happen like original one... secondly I have tested it on a large html code, around 170+ <*style> tags in html, so it adds 5 sub-arrays, matches[0] has code I mentioned above and the rest $matches[1]..[4] are empty with all 170 empty sub-arrays.. thanks for all your time and effort..

Comment: Believe me, the `.*?>.*?` will give lots of headache if you use regex for this task. Use regex where you need it, use DOM parser when you parse HTML.

Comment: @user1718343, Hello again. I just came back home and have some new updated solutions for you. I hope you'll find the right way

Comment: Thanks Roman.. I will try and update, but even previous worked after playing with that.. Thanks a LOT !..